# Perform MapReduce in Spark data frames

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce

[data]https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2016-01.csv

I don't understand how to perform mapreduce on dataframes using pyspark
i want to use .map(lambda x: (x,1)) and reduceByKey() which will give me the required output as
(VendorID,day,count) Eg: (1,3,5)
I have created a dataframe but dont understand how to proceed. Please guide.

This is the table I created, day column is generated from main datacolumn 'tpep_pickup_datetime'

[image]

Comment: use groupBy i would suggest for DF

Answer (score 0):

With dataframes you use the API's there, as pyspark does not have Dataset allowing map.

The equivalent with DF for pyspark is like this:

```
df.groupBy("c1," "c2").sum("c3").show(truncate=False)
```

or some other agg function in appropriate manner.